# How to include more than one HTML-form in a FLASK view?

Tags: python, html, forms, python-2.7, flask

I´m building a little web application using **python 2.7** and **flask** (my first one).

I´m trying to include three **HTML forms** in one **flask view** to have all three of the forms on one webpage:

1. One form to allow data upload (will be an XML-file)
2. One Button to start a python process, that performs analysis on the XML-file
3. One Button that allows download of the results of step 2

While I got it working, when using a separate view for each of the three steps, I somehow can´t get it done when trying to include all three steps in one view. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here´s my code so far. The HTML-code is included in the python script. Working with templates didn´t help me either. The HTML page is working, but the buttons don´t perform any action.

```
...
@app.route('/PAM', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start_PAM():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "Upload" in request.form.values():
                file = request.files['file']
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                    print "File upload complete !!"
                    return redirect('/PAM')
        elif "Start PAM" in request.form.values():
                import os
                os.system("D:\Python_Test\PAM\PAM_1st_Try.py")
                print "PAM Process Finished!!"
                return redirect('/PAM')
        elif "Download" in request.form.values():
                filename = "FILE.XML"
                return redirect(url_for('download_file', filename=filename))

    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Start PAM Process</title>
    <h1>XML Upload</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <p><h1>Start the PAM Process</h1>
    <form name='Start PAM' method='POST'>
    <p><input type="submit" value="PAM" class="submitButton"/>
    </form>

    <p><h1>Download Result</h1>
    <form name='Download' method='POST'>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Download" class="submitButton"/>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route("/downloads/<filename>")
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)

app.debug = True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? Your first design (3 separated functions) is much more straightforward and scalable. Even if the three operations are related, this is not a reason to put all the code in the same place.

Comment: I would like to show the three HTML-forms in one webpage. Is there a better way to do that besides pulling the three views into one ?? Sorry, if this is a stupid question. Still a newby.

Answer (score 1):

I think the step you're missing is to assign an action to the forms. At the moment the HTML doesn't know what to do with the form?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had actions defined before, when using HTML templates. Unfortunately it didn´t work. I tried again with the embedded HTML-code now, but it didn´t work either. Pushing the button just does nothing. It looks like the HTML is sending the information to the python script, but the script doesn´t take it.